# Many to many relation in GAE. Failing query

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've been modeling many to many relationships in gae using the classic `ListProperty` of db.Key instances.

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    _bars = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

    @property
    def bars(self):
        return Bar.gql("WHERE __key__ in :1", self._bars)

class Bar(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

    @property
    def bands(self):
        return Foo.gql("WHERE _bars = :1", self.key())

class QueryTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        db.delete(Foo.all().run())
        db.delete(Bar.all().run())

    def test_query_no_notification(self):
        bar_1 = Bar(name="asdf")
        bar_1.put()
        bar_2 = Bar(name="qwer")
        bar_2.put()
        foo = Foo()
        foo.put()
        self.assertEqual(len([bar for bar in foo.bars]), 0)

    def test_query_with_bars(self):
        bar_1 = Bar(name="asdf")
        bar_1.put()
        bar_2 = Bar(name="qwe")
        bar_2.put()

        foo = Foo()
        foo._bars.append(bar_1.key())
        foo.put()
        self.assertEqual(len([bar for bar in foo.bars]), 1)
```

In the code above, the first test is failing. When the `_bars` ListProperty is empty, the `Bar.gql("WHERE __key__ in :1", self._bars)`
 returns all Bar objects (instead of none).

However, if `_bars` does contain at least one element, the query runs fine.

I'm curious if this is a bug in GAE, or the way I'm writing the query is wrong...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This certainly look anomalous. Can you run AppStats, and see what underlying queries are being executed?

However, what you're doing is not the most efficient way. When you run a query like `SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE bar in :1`, the SDK breaks this up into one equality query for each item in the list, and executes them separately. You're attempting to look up items by key, however, and the Datastore has a built in method to do this. Replace the current query with this:

```
return Bar.get(self._bars)
```

Comment: the Bar.get solution works great. Will mark this as solved, though I'm curious on what's happening with the WHERE __key__ query...

Comment: @Ioan Appstats, as I suggested, should elucidate by showing what underlying queries are being executed.